# Cheapest GPU that is possible to mine on

Tags: gpu-mining, mining-hardware

What would be the cheapest GPU someone could mine on. It doesn't matter the speed, coins per watt, etc.
Just the cheapest, not for profit, just as a hobby.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cheapest GPU is the one you have available. I mean, you can start mining with an integrated GPU like an AMD Radeon HD 7480D and get around 50 H/s.

If you want a full list of GPU Benchmarks, feel free to check my website:

http://monerobechmarks.byethost5.com/

[Website's Reddit Thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/MoneroMining/comments/565r7k/gpu_cpu_benchmarks_for_minero_mining/)

[Website's Bitcointalk Thread](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1612690.0)

Answer (score 2):

An AES enabled ARMv8 build is the most efficient.  You can get a compatible ARMv8 system for < $100.  This is the cheapest way to mine and get started.  Although, you ask for GPU, this would technically be a CPU solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can mine on pretty much anything that still has driver support. My suggestion is to check eBay or Craigslist and choose one the cheapest one that still has updated drivers. I'm sure you can get something for less than $50.

Answer (score 1):

GTX1050 or RX460 - 4GB version are decent BUT GTX1060 or RX47x/RX57x better options for mining at this current date.
If you have money then anything above those.

Comment: You can go older school and get a GTX 750 ti or GTX 9xx but try get 4GB not sure about older AMD versions.

Comment: gtx 650 gets over 100h/s, 650 ti gets ~150h/s

Answer (score 0):

Grabbing one of the R9 290x (hashes at 470 h/s for me) for under $100, with shipping mine was $68 you just have to shop around, or some type of GPU that is producing visual artifacts at the graphic level but still works (I grabbed an HD7950 for $80 a couple months ago, and it hashes at 380 h/s)